# Keys only query, using a key

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to do a simple Key-Only query using a key (so to test the existence of it in the datastore).

Whats the simplest way in java of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking the existence of one entity by key, the simplest and cheapest would be to simply use `get()`:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey(kind, long) )
```

Get (1 read operation) is cheaper the query (1 read + 1 small): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html

Comment: The above will fetch the entire entity, therefore it isn't a Key only query.

Comment: Yes, but it does not matter. For testing the existence of Entity its the cheapest way (and probably fastest).

Comment: There's a chance that this is not fastest depending on the size of the entity. I think the charge for datastore bandwidth has gone now, so it's guaranteed to be cheapest I think.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible!

Try something like this:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query gaeQuery = new Query(entityName);
gaeQuery.setKeysOnly();     
gaeQuery.addFilter("__key__", FilterOperator.EQUAL, key);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(gaeQuery);
List<Entity> results = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));

Key elementKey = null;
if (results.size() == 1) {
    elementKey = results.get(0).getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the existence, you might use Victor's suggestion but fetch the count instead:

```
return datastore.prepare(gaeQuery)
    .countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1)) > 0;
```