# Objectify count async

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Is it possible to do an entity count in objectify in async mode (without blocking) ?

I can see a .count method which returns an int but that is a blocking call.

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying GAE low-level API `PreparedQuery.countEntities()` method is synchronous. Without support from Google, Objectify can't provide an async version.

If you want this feature, first put an enhancement request in the GAE issue tracker. If/when it shows up in the low level API, we can add it to Objectify.

Comment: Thanks. I have raised an issue in GAE issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11219. Hopefully this will get accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You "can" do a it but none of the options are pretty. When you mean async is it you know by the end of your code you will need a count, but wont be doing any changes to the datastore in the mean time? If so do a do a [async get](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async#Async_Queries) with a [.setKeysOnly()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402600/3877822). Do your thing while it works then do the .count at the end. That assumes no changes and you have enough time. If its something that doesn't get updated often you could use a [taskqueue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) to get a count and update a db stored field that keeps the count. But both those options will cost you ALOT of reads, and instance hours.

Personally I would code in a counter. Create an entity and whenever you do a change to the datastore update the [counter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters). That way its always up to date with minimal impact to your quotas.

Comment: Async get for keys only will be counted as small operation and small operations are free.